# Array de bitmaps disparando OutOfMemory mesmo tendo memória suficente

Tags: c#, memória, compressão-de-imagem

## Problema

Estou com problema no meu programa que quando o processo chega a mais de 1,5 GB de uso de memória o processo para de executar e exibi um erro de `OutOfMemory`.

No meu processo estou lendo um arquivo `.AVI` e guardando cada frame em um `Array de Bitmaps`,
para que eu possa executar depois em um player de forma sincronizada.

## Dúvida

Não sei se o Windows limita um `array` a 1,5 GB e por isso ele dispara um erro de memória mesmo tendo espaço suficiente para continuar. Alguém já teve esse problema e sabe alguma solução?

## Informações adicionais

São 4 arquivos em `30FPS` com tamanho de `7MB` cada.
Meu computador é `64Bits`, `Windows 7`, `8 GB de memória`.

Comment: Arquivos de vídeo, até onde eu sei, são compactados ao extremo. Você não está copiando bitmaps, você está convertendo a informação bastante compactada de cada frame para um formato milhões de vezes maior (eu não estou exagerando quando digo milhões). Com certeza deve haver formas melhores de se alcançar seu objetivo, se o que você quer é sincronia.

Comment: Sugiro abrir outra pergunta dizendo qual é o seu problema maior (sincronizar vídeo e áudio, talvez?). Talvez alguém consiga uma solução de outra forma.

Comment: @Renan obg pela rápida resposta. Então estou fazendo desse jeito pois eu consigo controlar melhor o player. Ex: posso escolher o ponto exato que quero do video. Mas essa minha pergunta serve tb para outras aplicações que usam array que acaba ficando mt grande e passando do tamanho de 1,5GB. Já tive esse tipo de problema em outro programa. Gostaria de saber msm se teria algum solução ou meio de resolver isso e aumentar o tamanho máximo do array.

Comment: Não sou entendido nessas técnicas, mas acho que você deveria usar algum tipo de buffer (todo player usa). Carregar todos esses frames em memória de uma vez só é muito ineficiente.

Comment: Armazenar TODOS os dados dos vídeos em memória pode não ser uma boa saída porque mesmo que o seu programa consiga endereçar haverá uma subutilização da memória. Porque você não lê os dados em pedaços (digamos, de 100 em 100 quadros)? Se você já sabe interpretar o formato (codec) do vídeo, "pular" para um determinado quadro é simplesmente fazer um `FileStream::Seek` no arquivo para a posição i * s (onde i = índice do quadro de 0 a n e s = tamanho do quadro em bytes).

Comment: @LuizVieira Vou tentar fazer dessa forma ! Acho que será a melhor forma. Obg :)

Comment: Por nada. :) De todas as formas, a sua pergunta parece um pouco ampla. Pelos comentários dá pra inferir que o seu problema é ler e reproduzir os dados de um arquivo de vídeo, mas a pergunta parece ser sobre limites de endereçamento de memória em matrizes no C#. Se for manter essa dúvida, talvez seja melhor editar a questão para ao menos incluir um exemplo de código sucinto (e facilmente reproduzível).

Comment: Rsouza, se quiser posso reformular a pergunta para você, considerando o que já foi discutido. E aí você acrescenta mais informações se necessário.

Comment: Embora a documentação seja um pouco confusa acerca disto, uma OutOfMemoryException ocorre quando não existe um bloco de memória contíguo disponível para o processo com a dimensão pretendida.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não acredito que seu problema seja uma limitação de memória, mas sim um aspecto prático de arquitetura. Ambientes que precisam lidar com conteúdos que não podem ser carregados e manipulados de maneira prática na memória física geralmente se utilizam de um mecanismo de carga parcial. Um deles é o *buffering*.

Em uma implementação de *buffer* clássica, o conteúdo imediatamente seguinte (definido por uma *janela de carga*) do cursor de leitura é carregado para a memória, numa operação chamada *read-ahead*. Opcionalmente, e dependendo do comportamento necessário, o conteúdo anterior também é enviado para o *buffer* (*read-behind*).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

À medida que seu cursor de leitura avança ou retrocede, conteúdo presente na direção oposta é descartado, e mais conteúdo é solicitado na direção onde a leitura acontece.

A grande vantagem desse método é que você mantém sua utilização de memória em termos aceitáveis.

Porém existe um custo: Se seu cursor de leitura se mover (*skip*) para uma posição além do presente no buffer, você tem que descartá-lo e recarregar a nova janela (re-buffering).

Se seu cursor de leitura se mover mais rápido do que a carga de conteúdo, você pode causar uma situação de *buffer underrun*.

Comment: Resposta massa para auxiliar com os conceitos! :) Mas, seria legal você citar a fonte da imagem (estou supondo que ela não é sua porque o texto está em inglês).

Comment: Obrigado, e entendo a preocupacao - porem a autoria da imagem eh minha, sim. O termo 'frame atual' seria 'current frame' em ingles. O nome do software que uso eh Gliffy Diagrams.

Comment: Cara, nem tinha visto "atual" ali. Foi mals. :)

Comment: Nem estressa, @LuizVieira, o motivo foi nobre ;)

Comment: Era isso que eu tinha em mente para tentar resolver esse problema. @OnoSendai . Obg :)

Answer (score 1):

Você não informou a versão do Framework em uso, mas a versão 4.5 dispõem de um atributo que permite ampliar a limitação de 2GB.
[gcAllowVeryLargeObjects - On 64-bit platforms, enables arrays that are greater than 2 gigabytes (GB) in total size.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Estou usando o 4.0. Vou dar uma olhada nesse link. Obg :)

Comment: Vi que isso funcionaria realmente se eu usasse minha aplicação em plataforma 64Bits. Só que eu uso DLLs de 32Bits então não posso compilar minha aplicação em 64Bits e sim em 32Bits. E Essa Funcionalidade do gcAllowVeryLargeObjects não funciona. Será que teria outro parâmetro para 32Bits? =X

Comment: O espaço de endereçamento para processos 32 bits está limitado em 2GB para aplicações o que representa algo em torno de 1.2 a 1.4 disponíveis. A alternativa é alterar seu programa de forma a carregar  somente o que tem de área disponível, tipo uma janela de visualização limitada ao espaço livre.